# Win10 Fall Creator's Update and FirePro w2100 makes Corel Draw drop to its knees

Tags: windows-10, coreldraw, amd-firepro

We are running Corel Draw on a computer with a FirePro w2100 graphics card.
Everything was fine until after the Win10 Fall Creator's update.
Now, Corel just crawls. Drawing, copy/paste, printing take FOREVER.
I've spoken to Microsoft, who blames AMD, and AMD who blames Microsoft.
I've tried the AMD "cleaner" to remove all AMD software and a few different versions of the driver, including the most recent but nothing works. 
I'm afraid of having to wait for a driver or Windows update to fix it.
Do I have any good options?

Comment: You might experiment with turning graphics hardware acceleration on and off from the GPU control panel, or from Corel Draw, if there is such a setting.

Comment: This sounds like a Corel Draw issue.  AMD has had stable 1709 drivers for months.  Have you tried patching Corel Draw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD got back to me this morning and here is the fix:

1. Launch Windows in Safe Mode
2. Remove the previous driver using the [Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html)
3. Install the [AMD FirePro AMD FireMV Unified Display Driver for Win 10 64 bit (Revision Number 17.Q4.1)](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/workstation/previous/detail?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064&rev=17.Q4.1)

Comment: As this answer was the one that solved the problem: would you mind tagging it as solution? that way, the question will be marked as answered and it won't spring up in a year's time as unanswered ;-)

Comment: I have 3 more hours before I can, but I will. thanks

Answer (score 0):

These ideas comes to mind

1. Call Corel and file a bug report with all the details you can provided.
2. Get a copy of the previous version of Windows 10, and re-install that in the meantime.